# how to give id and access the anchor tag in asp.net html page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added the id in the anchor tag and I want to use this id in my c# code to change the class name.

However, I am getting a parser error -

```
<a runat="server" id="btn_status_toggle" 
 class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#myModal" 
 onclick="fun(<%# Eval("ID")%>)">Status</a>
```

I don't know what is the problem.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 95:
>      Line 96:                         &RoleName=<%#
>   Eval("RoleName")%>'>Edit
>       Line 97:                         )">Status
>       Line 98:                     
>       Line 99:
>
> Source File: /ShowAdminData.aspx    Line: 97

Comment: where this anchor is inside ? (inside a gridview for example ?)

Comment: what is fun()? is it javascript function or a method in c# class

Answer (score 1):

change `onclick="fun(<%# Eval("ID")%>)"` to `onclick='fun(<%# Eval("ID")%>)'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use: `onclick='<%# "fun("+ Eval("ID") + ")" %>'`. Create the entire onclick value string inside the `<%# %>` block.

```
<a runat="server" id="btn_status_toggle" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick='<%# "fun("+ Eval("tocht_id") + ")" %>'>Status</a>
```